# Can't remove last item in mongoose array of type Schema.Types.ObjectId with ref

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my mongoDb database if I have 2 or more items in the "folders" array with ObjectIds,  I can remove all of them (except the last one) with the same function (below). But when there is only one ObjectId left in the array, mongoose does not remove it. The response form "updatedFolder" actually logs "folders: []" but the last item is still there. I'm not sure if it has something to do with my schema.

Schema

```
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  author: {},
  parentFolder: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Folder",
  },
  blalis: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Blali",
    },
  ],
  folders: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Folder",
      default: [],
    },
  ],
});
```

Updating in express with router.patch

```
router.patch("/:id", getFolder, async (req, res) => {
  //Here req.body.folders is [] (an empty array)
  if (req.body.folders !== undefined) {
      res.folder.folders = req.body.folders;
  }
  try {
    const updatedFolder = await res.folder.save();
    res.json({
      updatedFolder,
      message: "Folder updated.",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});
```

My getFolder function uses .populate, but I don't think that's the problem

```
async function getFolder(req, res, next) {
  let folder = null;
  try {
    folder = await Folder.findById(req.params.id).populate([
      {
        path: "folders",
      },
      { path: "blalis" },
    ]);
    if (folder === null) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Folder not found" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }

  res.folder = folder;
  next();
}
```

In the end on mongo Atlas, I still see the ObjectId, even though in the .patch it was set to an empty array: []

```
folders:Array
0: ObjectId("6237e6e8c4b9a82c10b74e1d")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this one was hard to track.

Before I removed the ObjectId, from the "folders" array. I deleted the ObjectId instance, so for some reason I was not able to remove the last item from the array if the instance was already deleted.

**SOLUTION: First remove the ObjectId from the array and then delete the actual instance**